# Tableview within Split View Controller

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to put a tableview controller into a split view controller... kind of like the settings app and mail app combined (the tiny section and large section have functioning tableviews that link to other pages). Can someone please provide working source code of this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Um, that's a built-in sample:

[image]